# Error uploading .zip file / unzipping using Kudu console in Azure

Tags: azure, zip, kudu

**SUMMARY:** A zip file that I am uploading to Azure using Kudu can not be unzipped because Kudu thinks that the file is an incomplete archive.

**DETAILS:** Using the Debug console in Kudu I am attempting to to upload a .zip file to a new site created in Azure.

I have previously done this successfully with other .zip file.

The .zip file was created on a Linux system, then downloaded to my Windows workstation. On the Windows workstation, I can open and view the contents of the zip file so I know that it is valid.

The size of the zip file as seen through windows is 506,504KB.

When I drag this .zip file to the Kudu interface, I can watch it count up to the full file size as it is uploading. If I then I list the contents of the directory that the file is uploaded to from the console command, the uploaded .zip file shows as 80KB.

Because of this, I can not manually unzip the file using the unzip -f  command from the console because Kudu thinks that the .zip file is only a partial archive. I also noticed that when the zip file is initially created on Azure, its initial size is created at 80KB and the file size does not change as the file is being uploaded.

I have checked to see that I have plenty of available disk space and I don't see that I have a limit on file sizes and as I previously said, I have used this technique with two other directories.

Any ideas here on what the problem could be or what I need to do to fix this? I eventually need to use this method to upload many other files from zipped archives.

Comment: I did find that if I ftp the file from my Windows system using FileZilla to my Azure site, the entire .zip file uploads corectly. I can then expand the file using the unzip <filename> correctly. Bug in Kudu??

Answer (score 2):

Kudu uses System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive ([doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)). It's possible that some zip files are not supported by this library, in which case you you will need to find an alternate way to zip it.

Answer (score 0):

In our case, we built in Linux and uploaded to a Azure function in windows. This didn't cause any issue before, but this particular function used a new package therefore it seems this it was causing the issue.

The solution was to build in windows, zip and deploy to windows. This worked fine.